# How to make a flight path projection if possible in Python?

Tags: python, animation, 3d, kml, altitude

I have latitude, longitude and altitude data and want to make a plot such as in the image below using Python. The map can be left out, it is unnecessary.
[image]

I have tried using the [mplot3d polygon plot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#polygon-plots) but can't figure out how to have varying x and y values such that it is not a straight line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way to do this is to use Google Earth.

Now there are two ways to tackle this. The first method is simple if you want a static picture. The second method allows animation of the flight path. Both are explained in this answer.

#### Method 1

Using the following Python code I have made a `KML` file which allows me to create a static visualization.

```
f = open('flight.kml', 'w')

#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2'>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
f.write("<Placemark>\n")
f.write("   <name>flight</name>\n")
f.write("   <LineString>\n")
f.write("       <extrude>1</extrude>\n")
f.write("       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>\n")
f.write("       <coordinates>\n")
for i in range(0,len(data['altitude']),10):  #Here I skip some data
    f.write("        "+str(data['LON_GPS'][i]) + ","+ str(data['LAT_GPS'][i]) + "," + str(data['altitude'][i]) +"\n")    
f.write("       </coordinates>\n")
f.write("   </LineString>\n")
f.write("</Placemark>\n")
f.write("</Document>")
f.write("</kml>\n")
f.close()
```

The code results in a `KML` file which in general looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
<Placemark>
   <name>flight</name>
   <LineString>
       <extrude>1</extrude>
       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
       <coordinates>
       54.321976,-4.90948,39232.0
       54.320946,-4.90621,39232.0
       ...
       ...
       52.329865,4.71601,0
       52.329693,4.71619,0
       </coordinates>
   </LineString>
</Placemark>
</Document></kml>
```

Once the `*.kml` file is made using the code above, in Google Earth one can simply import it using *File, Import...* Google Earth then automatically displays the image you see below.

[image: Result]

#### Method 2

I also finally figured out how to animate the flight. The solution I found is to split the single `<Placemark>` from the static answer up into several Placemarks. Adding `<TimeSpan>` info into each placemark then allows an animation to take place. In order to get the same visual I had to have beginning coordinates and end coordinates for each Placemark in order to create a proper `<LineString>`. The result can be found [in this video](https://youtu.be/MryXTZLvitA). The video is created using the `Record a Tour` button in Google Earth

```
f = open(fname+'.kml', 'w')

#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2'>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
f.write("   <name>flight</name>\n")
for i in range(1,len(data['altitude'])):        
    f.write("<Placemark>\n") 
    f.write("        <TimeSpan>\n          <begin>" + '2015-12-02T%02i:%02i:%02iZ' % (data['UTC_HOUR'][i], data['UTC_MIN'][i], data['UTC_SEC'][i]) + "</begin>\n        </TimeSpan>\n")        
    f.write("   <LineString>\n")
    f.write("       <extrude>1</extrude>\n")
    f.write("       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>\n")
    f.write("        <coordinates>" +str(data['LON_GPS'][i-1]) + ","+ str(data['LAT_GPS'][i-1]) + "," + str(data['altitude'][i-1]) + " "  +str(data['LON_GPS'][i]) + ","+ str(data['LAT_GPS'][i]) + "," + str(data['altitude'][i]) +"</coordinates>\n")    
    f.write("   </LineString>\n")    
    f.write("</Placemark>\n")
    
f.write("</Document>")
f.write("</kml>\n")
f.close()
```

The resulting `KML` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
   <name>A332_Conventional</name>
<Placemark>
        <TimeSpan>
          <begin>2015-12-02T08:45:13Z</begin>
        </TimeSpan>
   <LineString>
       <extrude>1</extrude>
       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>-0.85058,53.338535,39200 -0.81538,53.332012,39200</coordinates>
   </LineString>
</Placemark>
...
...
<Placemark>
        <TimeSpan>
          <begin>2015-12-02T09:27:03Z</begin>
        </TimeSpan>
   <LineString>
       <extrude>1</extrude>
       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>4.71361,52.331066,0 4.71498,52.330379,0</coordinates>
   </LineString>
</Placemark>
</Document></kml>
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your previous answer to include the additional information rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: @MichaelMolter Thanks for the tip. I have merged both answers into one now